# Обновить значение третьего по величине элемента в таблице с помощью SQL Update

Tags: sql, postgresql9.5

Есть таблица со столбцами `id, name, value`. Нужно изменить значение `value` у той строки, в которой `value` третий по величине во всей таблице.

Comment: 1) найти такую строчку 2) обновить её. В чём конкретно затруднение? order by limit offset?

Comment: затруднение в том, что я не знаю как передать эту строку в **update**

Comment: **order by limit offset** помог, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

помогло ***order by limit offset***

```
UPDATE table_name
set value=123
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM table_name
order by value DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2);
```